# Flash AS3 - enumerateFonts() and private browsing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, browser, fonts

A Flash AS3 application can use: 
    flash.text.Font.enumerateFonts(true) 
to get a list of the host computer's system fonts.

However, if the .swf is running on a browser in private mode (this applies to Chrome, IE, FF, etc), the list will be empty except for any font that happens to be embedded in the .swf

Does anyone know a workaround that will get a list of device fonts in spite of a browser's private mode?

Comment: This is likely by design, so any hack you may find may not last long and probably shouldn't be relied on.  Most users should accept limitations imposed by private browsing

Comment: Do you really need the end-user font list badly? Cant you just roll with having the best preferred font(s) embeded into your swf? If you say why you need the fonts there might be an end-solution for that which works even in private browsing

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is for a Flash application that lets users create simple visual designs (using colored shapes, uploaded bitmaps, and text). We do provide a few embedded fonts but we also like to give users the ability to use their own installed fonts too. 

This isn't a huge deal... I'm just hoping to avoid calls from confused customers who try to use the app when private browsing.